# connection to database 'zabbix faild:[2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)

Tags: zabbix

I'am the new user of zabbix.The OS is sentos7 and the vision of zabbix is 5.0. When I used it，I can't get any new data from web and frequent appearance of the following pop-up windows on the page.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaZd3.png)
I check the zabbix_server.log.It full of

```
connection to database 'zabbix' failed: [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111)
database is down:reconnecting in 10 seconds
```

I check the /var/lib/mysql,mysql.sock in there.and mysql is running.